# Update UI in between 2 await sentences

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I'm trying to implement the async-await stuff in a (fairly simple) application.
My goal is to update a busyIndicator in between awaits.

I don't know what, but I think I'm missing somehting essential in my understanding of the async await stuff.

```
private async void StartTest(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
        this.BusyMessage = "Init..."

        await Task.Delay(7000);


        var getData1Task = this.blHandler.GetData1Async();
        this.BusyMessage = "Retreiving data...";

        this.result1 = await getDeviceInfoTask;
        this.result2 = await this.blHandler.GetData2Async();

        this.BusyMessage = "Searching...";

        this.result3 = await this.blHandler.GetData3();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.IsBusy = false;
        this.BusyMessage = string.empty;
    }
}
```

The busyIndicator has a binding with `IsBusy` and `BusyMessage`.
When executing this code, I do get the busyIndicator showing "*Init...*" but it never changes to "*Retreiving data...*" or "*Searching...*".
Even worse: the ui freezes completely while executing the final `GetData3`.

Comment: What do those methods do? Are they really asynchronous?

Comment: Pause the debugger while it's frozen and look at the stack trace.

Comment: Is this code being called in an event handler? Is that handler marked as async?

Comment: I think the finally-block will be called _(too soon)_ when the first await _breaks_ the method. This can give some side effects. Can you put a breakpoint on the finally block?

Comment: @Baldrick This code is in a method in my viewmodel which is bind to a button.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It would be very bad if that actually was the case

Comment: @SLaks I was trying to use async-await instead of a backgroundworker. This is a fairly simple application so I thought I could give it a try.

Comment: Did you mark the containing method as `async`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, I did. I've updated my code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: That isn't the case, it acts like it should be. Tested it. So the finally is executed after.

Comment: Is any of the `GetData*` methods calling [Task.ConfigureAwait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx)? If so, perhaps the continuation (after `await`) is scheduled on a thread different from the UI thread (and then you try to manipulate the UI from the non-UI thread).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Marking a method as `async` (somewhat confusingly) doesn't necessarily mean that it will execute asynchronously. For that, you need to use `await` (as a warning will tell you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want to execute a synchronous method on a background thread, then asynchronously wait for it to finish in your UI code.

That's exactly what `Task.Run()` does.
It takes a delegate to run in the ThreadPool, then returns an `await`able Task that give you the result.

Comment: Thx. I'll read up on it and give it a try tomorrow. The answer of @MattSmith gave me already the essential part I was missing regarding the async await stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely `GetData1Async`, `GetData2Async` and `GetData3` are synchronous methods (that is, I'm guessing that while they do return a `Task` that they complete all their work synchronously).  In that case, the `await`s do not suspend the method (since the returned `Task` will be a completed task).  Thus, the method will continue all the way through as one big synchronous method, and the UI will never have a chance to update (since it is not pumping any messages during this time).

If you want more than a guess, show us the code for those three methods.

Comment: They are indeed synchronous methods returning a Task. I guess I've found the essential part that I was missing. I tought that those methods would run on a background thread. So I think I have to use a backgroundworker here instead of async await?

Comment: @Koen, Instead of a BackgroundWorker, see @SLaks answer regarding using `Task.Run()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try pushing message by Dispatcher like.

```
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
                        { this.BusyMessage = "Retreiving data..."; }));

    // Do Something 


   App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
                    { this.BusyMessage = "Filtering  data..."; }));

   // Do Something
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working copy stubbed out with some assumptions on my part.  Hope it helps.  I tested it in a running WPF app.  Note that there is no guarding in what you posted making sure this isn't "double-run" (we can start regardless the value of IsBusy, StartTest should probably ensure that).

```
public class StackWork : ViewModelBase
{
    private class MyHandler
    {
        private async Task<string> GetDataAsync(string result)
        {
            return await Task<string>.Run(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    return result;
                });
        }

        public async Task<string> GetData1Async()
        {
            return await GetDataAsync("Data1");
        }

        public async Task<string> GetData2Async()
        {
            return await GetDataAsync("Data2");
        }

        public async Task<string> GetData3()
        {
            return await GetDataAsync("Data3");
        }
    }

    private bool IsBusy { get; set; }

    private string _message = "";
    public string BusyMessage
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; RaisePropertyChanged("BusyMessage"); }
    }
    private MyHandler blHandler = new MyHandler();
    private Task<string> getDeviceInfoTask;
    private string result1 { get; set; }
    private string result2 { get; set; }
    private string result3 { get; set; }

    public StackWork()
    {
        getDeviceInfoTask = Task<string>.Run(() =>
            {
                return ("device info");
            });
    }

    public async void StartTest(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            this.IsBusy = true;
            this.BusyMessage = "Init...";

            await Task.Delay(7000);

            var getData1Task = /*this*/await/*was missing*/ this.blHandler.GetData1Async();
            this.BusyMessage = "Retreiving data...";

            //assuming this was Task.Run, put that in constructor
            this.result1 = getDeviceInfoTask/*this*/.Result/*was missing*/;
            this.result2 = await this.blHandler.GetData2Async();

            this.BusyMessage = "Searching...";

            //This was a little confusing because the name doesn't imply it is 
            //async, but it is awaited
            this.result3 = await this.blHandler.GetData3();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.IsBusy = false;
            this.BusyMessage = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```